# Obtain resource from POST php

Tags: php, mysql

Lets say I have a database full of info, and I want the user to find his info by inputting his ID. I collect the input of the user with:

```
'$_POST[PID]'
```

And want to put it into a resource variable like:

```
resource $result = '$_POST[PID]';
```

In order to print out their information like :

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                echo all their information
                echo "<br>";
            }
```

However I cannot create the resource variable because it is telling me that it is a boolean. How can I fetch that resource in order to print the list?

Comment: Why don't you get rid of the single quotes around the $_POST[PID]? then add a real sql command USING the ID you have collected from user input.

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. Here is a good [tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ) for PDO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several problems with this

First, a [resource](http://us.php.net/manual/en/resource.php) is something like a database result set, a connection (like `fsockopen`), etc. You can't just declare or typecast a variable into a result set

Second, you need to do something like SQL to fetch the data based on that ID. That involves connecting to the DB, running your query and **then** doing your `fetch_array`

Third, `mysql_` functions are depreciated. Consider using `mysqli` instead.

Comment: Would something like `$result = mysql_query($_POST[PID]);` work?

Comment: You ignored the fact that mysql_* is depreciated. It's not being maintained anymore so using mysql_* will not be a good way to develop something that should be easily maintained over the future.

Other than that, you still lack an sql command.

Comment: No. First, you're passing your parameter as the SQL. Second, you're wide open to SQL injection.

Comment: @remedy. So I tried
`$result = mysqli_query($connection, $_POST[PID]);`
Where `$connection` is the server and the post is the ID. However, it is telling me that:
`mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given` Which is why i am confused

Comment: It sounds like you need to use `mysqli_connect` and set it to `$connection`

Comment: Yes I already did that in a previous statement as `$connection = mysql_connect("theserver","myid","mypassword");` but it is still giving me that error.

Comment: `mysqli_connect`, not `mysql_connect`

Comment: That solved that problem, but now I got another. I have `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))` but that returns `mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given` which puts me back at the original problem.

Comment: Like I've said, $result needs to contain the sql command. For example $result = "'select id from table where id = 1";

Answer (score 0):

I think you're having problems displaying the result set.

Try this

```
$id = $_POST['PID'];
$result = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id ='.$id.'";

 while($row = mysqli_query($result))
        {
            echo $row[0];  //or whichever column you want to display. 
                           //$row[0] will display your   
                           // PK

        }
```