# mysqli_fetch_array parameter error

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this problem where I am trying to get input from the user and then display information. The user is meant to insert an ID number, obtained by `$_POST[PID]`, then I catch that in result and when I try to get the result and print their info. This is the code:

```
 $result = mysqli_query($connection, $_POST[PID]);

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
    echo some info
    echo "<br>";
 }
```

However such code yields this error:

`mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given`

How can I fix such error such that I am able to obtain the input and use it in `mysqli_fetch_array`

Comment: What's $_POST['PID']?

Comment: `$_POST[PID]` is a query ???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran `$_POST[PID]` is the command i am using to get the ID number from the user.

Comment: @user1404664, `insert into tbl where` is not valid, `where` with `insert`, is it `update` ?.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument for mysqli_query() must be a query.

For instance:

```
$var = "insert into tbl where field = '{$_POST['PID']}'";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $var);
```

Read it here:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp

Comment: On the query it states "Specifies the query string". Isn't that what i am passing with the post? The post is returning a number.

Comment: A query is an SQL statement, hence not a value.

Comment: Seriously, my answer is a sample. Do not use it in your code, use it as pattern instead.

Comment: I can't believe my answer was downvoted. Haha. Epic.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to my answer from your previous question(similar to this question)

[Obtain resource from POST php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21820190/obtain-resource-from-post-php/21820225?noredirect=1#comment33023642_21820225)

Answer (score -1):

Please learn about these functions to properly use them (Link [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php))

Instead of `$_POST[PID]` in `mysqli_query()` there must be some query string like

`"select * from tablename where id ='". $_POST['PID']."'`

Also, you need to enclose the key name within single quotes like `$_POST['PID']`

Comment: I tried this and it is giving me an error of unexpected string, am I supoused to substitute the "select * from tablename where id =" with something else?

Comment: That was an example. You need to customize that according to your database, table and fields. I strongly recommend you to spend some time learning the basics of sql and then you'll understand it properly. Visit the useful links posted by users here.